# Out of gas when calling smart contract function from web3/Meteor Dapp

Tags: web3js, testrpc, truffle-contract

The following smart contract function works when called in the **Remix-Solidity IDE** and connected to **testrpc**.

```
function submitAsset(string ownerName, string assetName, string assetDesc, string barcode, string sku, string countryOrigin) public returns (bool success) {
    if (!map_assets[msg.sender].initialized) {
        map_assets[msg.sender] = Asset(msg.sender, ownerName, assetName, assetDesc, barcode, sku, countryOrigin, true);
        assetAddresses.push(msg.sender);
        noOfAssets = assetAddresses.length;
        AssetSubmitted(msg.sender, ownerName, assetName, assetDesc, barcode, sku, countryOrigin, true);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

However, I get **out of gas** error when calling from Meteor/web3 app. The followings are the code in my javascript file:

```
instance.contract.submitAsset(ownerName, assetName, assetDesc, barcode, sku, countryOrigin).call({gas: estimateGas}, function(error, result) {
    if(!error) {
        console.log("yeah!: " + result);
    }
    else {
        console.log("ooops!: " + error);
    }
});
```

Please note that the estimated gas is 260385 (referred to the Solidity IDE). So, then I set **estimatedGas** to be 300000 in the javascript file - just to ensure it will go through. Still to no avail.

Again, I appreciate if anyone could point me to tips/advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with the following line,

`instance.contract.submitAsset.sendTransaction(prnName, assetName, assetDesc, barcode, sku, countryOrigin, {gas: estimateGas});`

use
**contract.methodName.sendTransaction(params, options)** 

and not
**contract.methodName(params).call()**

Answer (score 0):

Yes because `call` and `sendTransaction` (or `send`) are different on web3.

**call**: [doc](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-call)

Will call a “constant” method and execute its smart contract method in the EVM without sending any transaction. Note calling can not alter the smart contract state.

**sendTransaction**: [doc](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-send)

Will send a transaction to the smart contract and execute its method. Note this can alter the smart contract state.

PS: The doc links point to the web3 1.0, if think in your question you are referring to the web3 < 1.0, [the doc is here](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-methods)